# Link created in email from EJS template not working

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

In my EJS file I provide a email template that is sent out after the user does some action:

```
<p>
  Here is your link: 
  <a href='"/user/"<%=userId%>'>the link</a>
  <%=userId%>
</p>
```

When the user arrives in my inbox <%=userId%> displays the correct user ID; however the link above it is not clickable. This is what it displays when i inspect its elements:
[image]

How can I fix my syntax so I can send a clickable link. Thanks again

EDIT: include full image of console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href='/user/"<%=userId %>"'>the link</a>
```

Comment: I just cant get the formatting down. even when i do `<a href="google.com">link</a>` it wont work

Comment: included the full console for that paragraph. notice how the anchor tag doesnt have a href property attached to it

Comment: Please explain your solution. And also indicate the small code change because it could be easily overseen.